# MIGRATION of MySQL to oracle getting error

Tags: mysql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have migrated MySQL to oracle using oracle SQL developer. database, migrated successfully with triggers and sequence.but procedure is not migrated and in migrated repository it show cross mark on it.

Comment: Well open it and see where it shows the error.

Comment: can oracle sqldeveloper 17.2 migrate mysql store procedure to oracle

Comment: 17.2 is not a real version of SQL Developer. So what version are you really using?